# How to avoid transferring the same rows from mat-table in angular 2 using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented a simple table in angular 2 using angular material.

I have implemented a functionality in mat-table where I can select rows from mat-table and after clicking the **Transfer Rows** ,the selected rows data gets populated outside mat-table in the space provided for the Selected Rows to be displayed.

But as I selected and transfer a row from the mat-table ,the second time also the row is being transferred and I am getting the duplicate rows in the Selected Rows section.

Please access my sample example here..https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-app-material-h2lcps?file=app%2Faccount%2Faccount.component.ts

### Below shown is my output...

[image]

Can anybody please tell me how can avoid transferring duplicates....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether a selected element is already present in `selectedRows`, and only add it if that's not the case.

```
transferSelectedRows() {
     this.selection.selected.forEach(item => {
      let index: number = this.data.findIndex(d => d === item);
      if(!this.selectedRows.includes(this.data[index])) {
        this.selectedRows.push(this.data[index]);
      }
      console.log(this.data.findIndex(d => d === item));
      console.log(item);

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.dataSource.data);
    });
    this.selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

Comment: I have one more query..... in the same example i have implemented deleting rows functionality... I am able to delete the selected rows from mat-table.. But I want to delete the transferred rows from the selected rows section..

Comment: can you please access...https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-app-material-h2lcps?file=app%2Faccount%2Faccount.component.ts

Comment: can you tell me how can i select the transferred items and apply delete items functionality..?

Comment: In `removeSelectedRows()` you look for the element to remove with `this.data.findIndex(d => d === item);` and then remove it with `this.dataSource.data.splice(index,1);`.

You can do the same thing to the `selectedRows` array, i.e. `this.selectedRows.findIndex(d => d === item);` etc.

Comment: yes I am able to remove the transferred rows ,,, but only if i select the particular row in mat-table ... but i want to select the rows from the  selected Rows section and delete...